# htaccess mod rewrite even if folder exists

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm building a website and I just figured out that I have this problem.

When users go to ***www.website.com/something*** I want htaccess to open ***www.website.com/index.php?s=something*** , this works fine with my current redirect except if I have that "something" as existing folder.

The "s" stands for "subpage"

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/?$ /index.php?s=$1 [L]
```

I have problems only if the folder exists ( /js /css /images ..etc ) so when I try to access **www.website.com/images** it still displays the correct page BUT it shows this in the address bar **www.website.com/images/?s=images** . One thing to note is that if I change the ?s=images to ?s=images213123 the php still only recognizes the /images/ as $_GET['s'];

I'm not experienced with htaccess, but this is what I put together so far, maybe the problem is somewhere else and not in the line above. 
I tried moving the [L] to the 3rd rule, tried separating the problematic rule from the rest, tried everything I could with my limited knowledge, I couldn't get anything working.

Any hints or ideas are very appreciated!
Thank you in advance

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^[^.]+\.[^.]+$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,R=301]


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^u/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ /u.php?u=$1
RewriteRule ^p/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ /$1.php
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/userpage/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/?$ /c.php?s=$1&c=$2
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/?$ /index.php?s=$1 [L]


ErrorDocument 400 /index.php
ErrorDocument 401 /index.php
ErrorDocument 403 /index.php
ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
ErrorDocument 500 /index.php
```

Edit: Adding "DirectorySlash Off" and changing the conditions and rules as in @Jon Lin's answer fixed the issue. I also had to clear the Firefox cache to see the changes. This is my final htaccess that works fine for my purpose.

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
DirectorySlash Off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^[^.]+\.[^.]+$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,R=301]


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^u/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ /u.php?u=$1

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^p/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ /$1.php

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/userpage/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/?$ /c.php?s=$1&c=$2

# I intentionally skipped the conditions here
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/?$ /index.php?s=$1 [L]


ErrorDocument 400 /index.php
ErrorDocument 401 /index.php
ErrorDocument 403 /index.php
ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
ErrorDocument 500 /index.php
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rewrite conditions only get applied to the immediately following rule, so you have 1 condition and 4 rules. That 1 condition is only applied to the first rule, and the other 3 have no conditions tied to them. You need to make sure all 4 of your rules won't get applied to requests for existing files or directories:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^u/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ /u.php?u=$1

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^p/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ /$1.php

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/<userpage>/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/?$ /c.php?s=$1&c=$2

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/?$ /index.php?s=$1 [L]
```

Comment: @CristianBenescu it's because of mod_dir. Apache will always redirect requests for directories that are missing the trailing slash, if you want to turn this off you can add a `DirectorySlash off` but doing so makes it so people can view the contents of a directory even if there is an index file