# Internal redirect from exisiting folder to document root file with mod_rewrite

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I want to create an **internal** rewrite which delivers a .php file from the document root.

The following example shows how it should work:

> https://example.com/test should load the file https://example.com/template.php?a=test
>   https://example.com/test1 should load the file https://example.com/template.php?a=test1

I've already written a RewriteRule:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)$ template.php?a=$1 [NC,END]
```

This rule works expect for one case. If the folder **exists**, in this example "test", it will result in a redirect loop. I presume that the reason for this behaviour is that the web server navigates to "/test" and then looks for "template.php". As there is no file (because "template.php is in the document root) the redirect fails.

How can I fix this behaviour? If the pattern matches there should always be an internal redirect no matter if the folder exists or not.

Comment: Do you have any other rules?

Comment: No, I disabled all of them. The only thing that was enabled was `Options -Indexes`. But if I access the page without this "rule", it just displays me the content of /test and adds "/?a=test".

Comment: Its probably  due to your other rules when they were active Your browser cached them. Try clearing your browser cache.

Comment: Didn't help. The problem is that looks for template.php inside the /test folder and not in the document root.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28928776/htaccess-mod-rewrite-even-if-folder-exists) question, I figured out how to rewrite even if the folder exists: I added `DirectorySlash Off` to my .htaccess.

From the apache [documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_dir.html#directoryslash):

> The DirectorySlash directive determines whether mod_dir should fixup URLs pointing to a directory or not.
>
> Typically if a user requests a resource without a trailing slash,
>   which points to a directory, mod_dir redirects him to the same
>   resource, but with trailing slash [...]

Furthermore, I added another rewrite rule which removes the last trailing slash.

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]
```

Now the following works:

> https://example.com/test loads the file https://example.com/template.php?a=test
>
> https://example.com/test/ redirects to https://example.com/test which
>   loads the file https://example.com/template.php?a=test